How to click button with Playwright without id
I am using Playwright to log into a site and extract some data. After logging in, I have to click a button to specify what type of user I am. There are two of these buttons, and after inspecting the webpage, both look pretty much the same.
For the first button, which I don't want to click:
<div ng-repeat="model in vm.AvailableUserModes" ng-scope>
   <div class="panel panel-default ng-isolate-scope tnt-busy-min-height tnt-busy-truncate" 
   tnt-  busy-bool="vm.SettingUserMode" position: relative;>
      ...
      <div class='panel-body'>
         ...
         <button type="button" class="btn btn btn-lg btn-block btn-default" 
         ng-click="vm.SetUserModeForCurrentUser(model)" style="padding-top:5px;"> == $0
            "Continue as " 
            <span ngl-bind="model.Name|splitCamelCase" class="ng-binding"> User1</span>
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

And for the second button, which I do want to click:
<div ng-repeat="model in vm.AvailableUserModes" ng-scope>
   <div class="panel panel-default ng-isolate-scope tnt-busy-min-height tnt-busy-truncate" 
   tnt-  busy-bool="vm.SettingUserMode" position: relative;>
      ...
      <div class='panel-body'>
         ...
         <button type="button" class="btn btn btn-lg btn-block btn-default" 
         ng-click="vm.SetUserModeForCurrentUser(model)" style="padding-top:5px;"> 
            "Continue as " 
            <span ngl-bind="model.Name|splitCamelCase" class="ng-binding"> User2</span>
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

For logging in, the buttons were of the type 'submit', so I was able to use page.click(button[type=submit]). Using page.click(button[type=button]) doesn't work (it can't find the element and keeps searching), but I don't know what else I can use to locate these buttons, or how to pick only the second one.
Here is the my code (with URL, username, and password removed):
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with sync_playwright() as p:
    # Open Browser
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False, slow_mo=500)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto('URL', timeout=0)
    
    # Log In
    page.fill('input#Username', 'username')
    page.click('button[type=submit]')
    page.fill('input#password', 'password')
    page.click('button[type=submit]')

    # Continue as User2
    page.is_visible('div.panel-heading')    # wait for User2 button to appear

    # first attempt to click User2 button does not find element and terminate
    page.click('button[type=button]')     
    # when exiting manually, message below shows in terminal
       #   - retrying click action, attempt #17
       #   - waiting 500ms
       #   - waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
       #   - element is not visible

    # unable to locate with text using await because SyntaxError: 'await' outside function
    # await page.locator('button:text("Continue as User2")').click();


What's 'URL'? Showing the HTML is good, but pages are dynamic and there are a lot of reasons why something might not be clickable (shadow DOM, iframes, cloudflare blocks, visibility, arbitrary JS timing....), so you generally need to share the actual site to ensure reproducibility. If it's behind auth, please try to recreate the site's behavior specific to the issue at hand. Avoid timeout=0--that's a potentially infinite loop that's hard to debug. You're using sync playwright, so you don't need await at all here.

It is behind auth. I'm not sure how to recreate the site's behavior but I'll look into it.

As mentioned above, the code you already have, page.locator('button:text("Continue as User2")').click(); should work. Just remove the await. If that doesn't work, then you have some site-specific behavior that I'd have to see and examine to debug, because it could be one of dozens of possible scenarios.
